# ReferenceError: windowTopScroll is not defined, when running tests with jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am trying to run a test on a file where `windowTopScroll()` is called on `mounted` method.

Jest is throwing `ReferenceError: windowTopScroll is not defined`

Here is my code for the test.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import sinon from 'sinon'
import WorkTimeline from '../../components/WorkTimeline.vue';
import { createLocalVue, mount, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';

Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['name']
describe("WorkTimeline.test.js", () => {
    const windowTopScroll = jest.fn()
    test('renders WorkTimeline Slider', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(WorkTimeline, {
            mocks: {
                $t: () => {},
                windowTopScroll: jest.fn()
            },

        });
        expect(windowTopScroll).toHaveBeenCalled();



    });
```

Comment: This might not be the problem but i notice that you do not send in your variabel windowTopScroll declared above the test. You simply send in an object called windowTopScroll that you set to jest.fn(). And therefore expect(windowTopScroll).toHaveBeenCalled(); will always fail.

Comment: @Achtung, nice catch! could you compose official answer?

Comment: @skyboyer I suspect it wont solve the problem. This bug shouldnt result in windowTopScroll being undefined.

Comment: @Achtung  thank you for the quick response.
Didn't solve the problem by adding it to top of the test.
A general question - there are many other functions in mounted function in my other files too, how to deal with these reference errors? 
How to let jest know that the function is available?